# Get the maximum field value of different row's between different tables and its id's

Tags: mysql, max, row, field

So we got four tables T1,T2,T3,T4

Each table has four columns, id,1,x,2 (id is primary key auto incremented in all tables) and all of them are populated with numbers (40-50 rows each).

How can I compare the first field of each table and column (and same for all the remaining fields) and display the maximum field for each column and its id?

For example, compare column 1/field 1 of T1 with column 1/field 1 of T2 and column 1/field 1 of T3 display the maximum and its id and then do the same for column 2/field 1 OF T1/T2/T3/T4/ etc etc and each of their respective fields for all 40 rows ?

I have read about UNION and JOINS but I don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

TABLE 1

```
ID | 1 | X | 2 |
1   10   20  30
2    5   45   6
3    3   11   12
4    0   14   23
```

TABLE 2

```
ID | 1 | X | 2 |
1   100 200  300
2    50 405  60
3    30 101  102
4    0  104  203
```

ETC ETC

we need to compare the 10 of table 1 column 1 row 1 id=1 with 100 of table 2 row/column/id=1 then the same for x and 2 column.

Comment: col1/field1? SQL databases aren't spreadsheets. What's in 1/1 for one query is not necessarily what'll be in 1/1 for some other query, e.g. if you change the sort order as a trivial example.

Comment: ok column1/row1, column2/row1, column3/row1 etc etc

Comment: doesn't matter. "rows" aren't a constant thing in DBs. what's in a particular "row" depends ENTIRELY on how you're querying the DB to get a recordset containing rows.

Comment: ok let me be clear

Comment: show some sample tables and what you expect for the output.

Comment: sorry dont know how to enter new line

Comment: don't put formatted/structure text into comments. it's utterly unreadable/useless. You can't put newlines into comments.

Comment: and now that you've posted that text, the question is easy. you don't compare "rows". You compare RECORDS. the db doesn't care "where" a record is. you just tell it which records you want to compare, which means you use those `id` fields. `select ... from A join B on A.id=B.id`

Comment: sorry can you be more specific ? select '1' from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.id ? and how does this work for 4 tables then ?